# How may I return an iterator over the keys of a HashMap that clones the keys?

Tags: rust, hashmap, iterator, clone

I am defining a trait called `ShyAssociation` that returns a lazy iterator of the keys of an associative structure. The iterator should either borrow the keys as immutable or clone them. The keys are always `&'static str.` All I need is an iterator that returns `&'static str`.

Here is the trait with my attempt at the method for the `keys` iterator:

```
use std::collections::{hash_map::Keys, HashMap};

#[derive(Clone, PartialEq, Debug)]
pub enum ShyValue {
    Boolean(bool),
    Integer(i64),
    Rational(f64),
    String(String),
    Error(String),
}

pub trait ShyAssociation {
    fn keys(&self) -> Keys<&'static str, ShyValue>;
}

impl ShyAssociation for HashMap<&'static str, ShyValue> {
    fn keys(&self) -> Keys<&'static str, ShyValue> {
        self.keys().cloned()
    }
}
```

It won't compile.

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/lib.rs:18:9
   |
18 |         self.keys().cloned()
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected struct `std::collections::hash_map::Keys`, found struct `std::iter::Cloned`
   |
   = note: expected type `std::collections::hash_map::Keys<'_, &'static str, _>`
              found type `std::iter::Cloned<std::collections::hash_map::Keys<'_, &str, _>>`
```

**UPDATE:**

I am attempting a variation on Alexander Huszagh's answer, but have a syntax error:

```
use std::collections::{hash_map::Keys, HashMap};

#[derive(Clone, PartialEq, Debug)]
pub enum ShyValue {
    Boolean(bool),
    Integer(i64),
    Rational(f64),
    String(String),
    Error(String),
}

pub trait ShyAssociation<'a> {
    fn keys(&self) -> Box<Iterator<Item=&'static str> + 'a>;
}

impl<'a> ShyAssociation<'a> for HashMap<&'static str, ShyValue> {
    fn keys(&self) -> Box<Iterator<Item=&'static str> + 'a> {
        Box::new<(Iterator<Item=&'static str> + 'a)>(self.keys().cloned())
    }
}
```

The error message is on the "str" in the Iterator Item definition for keys:

```
expected `:`, found `str`

expected `:`rustc
shy_association.rs(59, 42): expected `:`
```

Comment: Concretely, it's unclear what's wrong with [`HashMap::keys`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#method.keys), perhaps combined with [`Iterator::cloned`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.cloned).

Comment: Combining HashMap::keys with Iterator::cloned looks like what I need. Didn't know about the latter. You may post this as the answer. I am just a frustrated C# programmer who loves LINQ and just can't figure out Rust iterators.

Comment: As for trying to create an MRE, my problem is that when I find individual solutions to problems that I find on stack overflow, I have troubles composing them together without language impossibilities intruding. For example, getting separate solutions to PartialEquals and Clone to work together for a Trait object took me two months of research and trials! Very frustrating. (This coming from an MIT educated programmer who has worked in 28 other languages over a career of thirty years as a software engineer!)

Comment: I reduced the code example. I tried your suggestion, but do not know how to call it correctly and specify the return type correctly.

Comment: Change your return type to: `iter::Cloned<Keys<&'static str, ShyValue>>`.

Comment: If you would like to define an object method or free function (it won't work in a trait), you can also use `impl Iterator<Item=&'a str>` for any Rustc >= 1.27, where `'a` is the lifetime of the HashMap.

Comment: Please do not edit your question to ask new questions ([“Follow on” question vs edit to original - when to use which?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/290746/155423)). Feel free to ask the answerer for clarifications in a comment on the answer, or ask a new question (with an appropriately created [MRE] for *that* question).

Comment: Also, please take the time to learn from the edits we do to your question. See how the error message in your first question contains the information about which lines are causing the error? That's because I directly copied the error message from the compiler. Please always paste the exact and entire error that you're getting. Sometimes trying to interpret an error message is tricky and it's actually a different part of the error message that's important.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I read your link concerning follow on questions, which makes the policy clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that you're manually specifying a type that doesn't match the return type. `iter::Cloned<Keys<_, _>>` is not the same as `Keys<_, _>`. A simple fix is to change your return type to `iter::Cloned<Keys<&'static str, ShyValue>>`.

```
pub trait ShyAssociation {
    fn keys(&self) -> iter::Cloned<Keys<&'static str, ShyValue>>;
}

impl ShyAssociation for HashMap<&'static str, ShyValue> {
    fn keys(&self) -> iter::Cloned<Keys<&'static str, ShyValue>> {
        self.keys().cloned()
    }
}
```

If would like to return a type that implements a trait (which will not work in the above example, since this is only valid for non-trait functions and methods), you may also do:

```
pub fn keys<'a>(hash_map: &'a HashMap<&'static str, ShyValue>) -> impl Iterator<Item = &'a str> {
    hash_map.keys().cloned()
}
```

If you would like to use `Box<dyn Iterator>` so you may use it in a trait method, you may do:

```
pub trait ShyAssociation {
    fn keys<'a>(&'a self) -> Box<(dyn Iterator<Item = &'static str> + 'a)>;
}

impl ShyAssociation for HashMap<&'static str, ShyValue> {
    fn keys<'a>(&'a self) -> Box<(dyn Iterator<Item = &'static str> + 'a)> {
        Box::new(self.keys().cloned())
    }
}
```

The `'a` lifetime is necessary in order to limit the lifetime of the iterator to that of the `HashMap`.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. I am trying to return a Boxed trait following your lead, but get a syntax error.

Comment: @PaulChernoch, Updated per your suggestions.

Comment: Thanks! I can never figure out where to put those pesky lifetimes. I new I needed to correlate it with the HashMap's lifetime, but botched it.